# Bison/Flex strange result for some input

Tags: c++, bison

I extracted part of my project in order to show a strange effect of my parser:
my goal is to translate a syntax like ADD(VAL(2),VAL(5))... in C++
In the following you can find the light flex and bison files:

```
%{
#include <string>
#include "expression.tab.h"
void yyerror(char*);
int yyparse(void);

char linebuf[500]; //for output the row in case of syntax error

%}

blanks          [ \t\n]+
text            [a-zA-Z0-9]+|[0-9]+.[0-9]+
%%

\n.*            { /* saving the next row in case of syntax error */
                  strncpy(linebuf, yytext+1, sizeof(linebuf)); /* save the next line */
                  yyless(1);      /* give back all but the \n to rescan */
                }

{blanks}        { /* ignore */ };

"("             return(OPEN);
")"             return(CLOSE);
"SET"           return(SET);
"STORE"         return(STORE);
"MUL"           return(MUL);
"ADD"           return(ADD);
"DIV"           return(DIV);
"SUB"           return(SUB);
"ABS"           return(ABS);
"IFEL"          return(IFEL);
"NOT"           return(NOT);
"AND"           return(AND);
"OR"            return(OR);
"GEQ"           return(GEQ);
"LEQ"           return(LEQ);
"GREATER"       return(GREATER);
"LESS"          return(LESS);
"EQ"            return(EQ);
"VAR"           return(VAR);
"VAL"           return(VAL);
"GET"           return(GET);
","             return(S);

{text}          { yylval.str_val=(char*)strdup(yytext);
                  return(IDENTIFIER);
                }

.               return yytext[0];

%%

void yyerror(char *s){ 
    printf("<ERR> %s at %s in this line:\n", s, yytext);
    }

int yywrap (void){
    }

int main(int num_args, char** args){
    if(num_args != 2) {printf("usage: ./parser filename\n"); exit(0);}
    FILE* file = fopen(args[1],"r");
    if(file == NULL) {printf("couldn't open %s\n",args[1]); exit(0);}
    yyin = file;
    yyparse();
    fclose(file);
}
```

And

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
%}

//Symbols
%union
{
    char *str_val;
    int int_val;
};

%token OPEN;
%token CLOSE;
%token SET;
%token STORE;
%token MUL;
%token ADD;
%token DIV;
%token SUB;
%token ABS;
%token IFEL;
%token AND;
%token OR;
%token NOT;
%token GEQ;
%token LEQ;
%token GREATER;
%token LESS;
%token EQ;
%token GET;
%token S; /* separator */
%token VAR;
%token VAL;

%token <str_val> IDENTIFIER

%type <str_val> Code
%type <str_val> Exp
%type <str_val> Cond
%type <str_val> Check
%type <str_val> Var

%start Code

%%

Code:
    /* empty */
    {
        string res = "";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | SET OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){\n\tint x = "+t1+";\n\tprintf(\"%d\n\",x);\n\treturn 1;\n};";
        printf("%s\n",res.c_str());
    }
    | STORE OPEN VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $5;
        string t2 = $8;
        string res = t1+" = "+t2+";";
        printf("%s\n",res.c_str());
    }
    ;

Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string t3 = $7;
        string res = "("+t1+" ? "+t2+" : "+t3+")";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | ADD OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"+"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | SUB OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"-"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | MUL OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"*"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | DIV OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t2+"==0) ? (0) : ("+t1+"/"+t2+"))";  //TBD substitute (0) in order to raise exception of div for zero
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | ABS OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "(("+t1+">0) ? "+t1+" : ("+t1+"*(-1)))";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    ;

Cond:
    NOT OPEN Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "(("+t1+") ? false : true)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | AND OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+" && "+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | OR OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+" || "+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | Check
    ;

Check:
    GREATER OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+">"+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | LESS OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"<"+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | EQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"=="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | GEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+">="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    | LEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"<="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = (char*)res.c_str();
    }
    ;

Var:
    VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        $$ = (char*)t1.c_str();

    }
    | VAL OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3;
    }
    | GET OPEN CLOSE
    {
        $$ = strdup("1");
    }
    ;

%%
```

Everything works fine with a small formula but something changes with a bigger one.
With this input:

```
SET(ADD(MUL(VAL(3),SUB(VAL(5),VAL(2))),IFEL(GEQ(IFEL(EQ(VAL(16),MUL(VAL(2),VAL(8))),VAL(11),VAL(10)),VAL(10)),MUL(VAL(3.2),VAL(4)),ADD(VAL(2),VAL(1)))))
```

My voutput is the following:

```
$ ./expression1 test.txt 
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = (((16==(2*8)) ? true : fa+((((((16==(2*8)) ? true : false) ? 11 : 10)>=10) ? true : false) ? (2 : (2+1)));
    printf("%d
",x);
    return 1;
};
```

I can't get the reason of such bad result

```
(((16==(2*8)) ? true : fa+((((((16==(2*8)) ? true : false) ? 11 : 10)>=10) ? true : false) ? (2 : (2+1)));
```

As you can see also the number of open brackets and closed brackets are different.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your individual productions are assigning a `char *` to `$$` that is pointing to the return value from `str.c_str()`. When `str` goes out of scope at the end of the block, the memory that pointer is pointing to may be freed by the string destructor, and accessing it results in undefined behavior. To overcome this, you can allocate memory for the string that will persist after the original string goes out of scope, [`strdup`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) can be used for this.

Using your bison file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
extern int yylex();
extern void yyerror(char*);
%}

//Symbols
%union
{
    char *str_val;
    int int_val;
};

%token OPEN;
%token CLOSE;
%token SET;
%token STORE;
%token MUL;
%token ADD;
%token DIV;
%token SUB;
%token ABS;
%token IFEL;
%token AND;
%token OR;
%token NOT;
%token GEQ;
%token LEQ;
%token GREATER;
%token LESS;
%token EQ;
%token GET;
%token S; /* separator */
%token VAR;
%token VAL;

%token <str_val> IDENTIFIER

%type <str_val> Code
%type <str_val> Exp
%type <str_val> Cond
%type <str_val> Check
%type <str_val> Var

%start Code

%%

Code:
    /* empty */
    {
        string res = "";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | SET OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "#include <stdio.h>\nint main(){\n\tint x = "+t1+";\n\tprintf(\"%d\\n\",x);\n\treturn 1;\n};";
        printf("%s\n",res.c_str());
    }
    | STORE OPEN VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $5;
        string t2 = $8;
        string res = t1+" = "+t2+";";
        printf("%s\n",res.c_str());
    }
    ;

Exp:
    Var
    | IFEL OPEN Cond S Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string t3 = $7;
        string res = "("+t1+" ? "+t2+" : "+t3+")";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | ADD OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"+"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | SUB OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"-"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | MUL OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "("+t1+"*"+t2+")"; 
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | DIV OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t2+"==0) ? (0) : ("+t1+"/"+t2+"))";  //TBD substitute (0) in order to raise exception of div for zero
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | ABS OPEN Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "(("+t1+">0) ? "+t1+" : ("+t1+"*(-1)))";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    ;

Cond:
    NOT OPEN Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string res = "(("+t1+") ? false : true)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | AND OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+" && "+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | OR OPEN Cond S Cond CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+" || "+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | Check
    ;

Check:
    GREATER OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+">"+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | LESS OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"<"+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | EQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"=="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | GEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+">="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    | LEQ OPEN Exp S Exp CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        string t2 = $5;
        string res = "(("+t1+"<="+t2+") ? true : false)";
        $$ = strdup(res.c_str());
    }
    ;

Var:
    VAR OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        string t1 = $3;
        $$ = strdup(t1.c_str());

    }
    | VAL OPEN IDENTIFIER CLOSE
    {
        $$ = $3;
    }
    | GET OPEN CLOSE
    {
        $$ = strdup("1");
    }
    ;

%%
```

And that returns

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int x = ((3*(5-2))+((((((16==(2*8)) ? true : false) ? 11 : 10)>=10) ? true : false) ? (3.2*4) : (2+1)));
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 1;
};
```

as expected.

Note that nowhere are we freeing the memory allocated by `strdup`, so this technically results in a memory leak, but I think it's an appropriate and easy solution for your specific problem.

(I also added another backslash in the `printf` string, assuming that was the intended behavior.)